# WKWebView vs SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, ios8, uiwebview, ios9, wkwebview

We have `WKWebView` in iOS 8 and `SFSafariViewController` in iOS 9. 
I know that `WKWebView` subclasses from `UIView`, and that `SFSafariViewController` subclasses from `UIViewController`.
They are essentially different.

My question is about memory management between these two components.
Quoted from developers at Facebook, [Reducing FOOMs in the Facebook iOS app](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1146930688654547/reducing-fooms-in-the-facebook-ios-app/)

> WKWebView — that actually performs most of its work in a separate process, which means that most web-view-related memory usage would not be attributed to our process.

This helps a lot in preventing our app from being killed because our process consumes a large amount of memory.

Does SFSafariViewController handle web-view-related memory in a separate process like WKWebView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Safari View Controller runs in a separate process from your application.
Here's [a link to WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=504).